# Remove FaceBook Like

Tags: facebook

I have a page that allows for user uploaded content.  They can then share the link to that page where users can "like it".  We use the og meta tags to create a "link" like which has a preview of the text entered.

If content is deemed to be offensive or a violation of our TOS, I'm working on a process to remove the content from our site.

I'm guessing the answer is no, but is there a known way to remove that content from facebook?  Or, atleast tell facebook to update the contents of the "like" link text to show our new "this content is in violation of our TOS?"

I realize I can't alters someones wall, but just wondering if there was anything else I could proactively due to resolve matters such as this.

Should we contact facebook directly and let them know the content was removed?

Sorry if this information has been covered elsewhere, we are new to the whole "facebook" integration stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retroactively change what a user liked

```
Should we contact facebook directly and let them know the content was removed?
```

Not feasible. Your best bet is to just be proactive about content before its open to the public anyway.

Comment: Thanks!  We do filter for certain offensive phrases, but sometimes the inclusion of personal data (like someone pastes someones name) is hard to detect (as offensive).  We just give our users the ability to notify us so we can review / remove.  I just wanted to make sure we were doing everything we could.